# De Morgan minimization

Tags: boolean-algebra

De Morgan

$$y=\overline{a+\overline{b(\overline{c+d})}}+\bar{b}$$
$$y=\bar{a}(\overline{\overline{b(\overline{c+d})}})+\bar{b}$$
$$y=\bar{a}(b(\overline{c+d}))+\bar{b}$$
$$y=\bar{a}(b\overline{cd})+\bar{b}$$
$$y=\bar{a}b\overline{cd}+\bar{b}$$

This is as far as I've got on my simplification:

$$x+\bar{x}y=1+0\cdot1~or~0+1\cdot1$$

So it might be

$$1+0~or~0+1=1$$

But

$$\bar{a}b\overline{cd}+\bar{b}=\overline{acd}(b+\bar{b})=\overline{acd}\cdot 1=\overline{ac}d$$

### I can't understand why it's will be \$y=\overline{acd}+b\$, so how I must to minimize this \$b\$?

Maybe I solved it!
a'bc'd'+b'=
(a+b'+c+d)'+b'=
((a+b'+c+d)b)'=
(ab+b'b+cb+db)'=
(ab+1+cb+db)'=
((a+c+d)b)'=
(a+c+d)'+b'=
=a'c'd'+b' Is it correct?

Comment: Ok thank you for editing your problem. Now I need a little clarification. What do you mean by your last sentence, _"I can't [understand] why..."_ I don't understand what you're trying to say nor how you're relating this to your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs and attempt at a solution (even if you do have the answer)

Comment: @KingDuken the solution of the function should be this y=a'c'd'+b but I don't know how to get it.. I can't undersand how to semplify b+b' so why b it's desaper? Cos for the rule a+a'=1 so it's must be just a'c'd' but in the correct answer of this exercise is a'c'd'+b

Comment: @laptop2d A small question. If one has done his homework but can't solve it. What should he do? Do not ask for the explanation of why it's wrong?

Comment: You just need the intuitive connection...think about it this way.  If b is false, the result will be unconditionally true due to the right term.  Therefore, the only time the left term is needed is when b is true.  So if the left term will affect the result in any way, it can be assumed that b is true--so it's optimized out with that assumption.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Ok I don't understand well. For addition 0+1=1 For moltiplication 0*1=0. Semplifcation x+x'y 1+0*1 or 0+1*1 So it might be 1+0 or 0+1 (it's the same)=1. But a'bc'd'+b'=a'c'd'(b+b')=a'c'd'(1)=a'c'd'

Comment: Get as far as you can but provide an answer, and tell us where your stuck.

Comment: Suppose I tell you that I'll be there if (a) my car starts, or if (b) my car doesn't start but I can get an Uber.  Logically, I'm saying the same thing if I say "I'll be there if my car starts or I can get an Uber."  I don't need the additional condition specifying that I'm getting an Uber only if my car doesn't start...if my car started, I'll be there Uber or not.  The result is whether I show up, not how I got there.  See the analogy?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis ok I understood your logic with the car, but not with the semplification. How can I say that I'll remove b because I've got a b '?

Comment: @laptop2d My stuck is on this semplification. I can't understand how to do it well. So I don't know why my answer it's wrong.

Comment: Maybe I solved it! a'bc'd'+b'=(a+b'+c+d)'+b'=((a+b'+c+d)b)'=(ab+b'b+cb+db)'=(ab+1+cb+db)'=((a+b+d)b)'=(a+b+d)'+b'=a'b'd'+b' Is it correct?

Comment: No a'b'd'+b' is not correct.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat a'c'd'+b' I wrote down wrongly the solution and didn't see it..

Comment: Voting to close, as this is not an electronics question. While boolean algebra is certainly necessary for designing digital logic electronics, pure math questions are better off at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -1):

De Morgan
$$y=\overline{a+\overline{b(\overline{c+d})}}+\bar{b}$$
$$y=\bar{a}(b(\overline{c+d}))+\bar{b}$$
You are correct up to this point.  Based on the comments, you are correct for the rest, but you fooled up the mathjax syntax as you deMorganed.  Corrected we have:
$$y=\bar{a}b\bar c \bar d+\bar{b}$$

You are also headed in the correct direction:
$$X+\bar{X} Y = X + Y$$

Which is the redundancy law.  The inclusion of \$X\$ means the \$\bar X\$ in \$\bar X Y\$ is redundant.

Comment: Yes cos  x(y+y') + y(x+x')=x+y